# How to convert ArrayList<String?> to List<CharSequence> in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I am facing this issue

I have an `ArrayList<String?>` and I have to pass it to a function that accepts `List<CharSequence>`
I tried to find a way to convert them but couldnt, How can I convert `ArrayList<String?>`  to `List<CharSequence>` in kotlin

Comment: In view of Tenfour04's comment: what should happen if the ArrayList contains any nulls?  Should it ignore them, and create a List with only the non-null items, or should it give a runtime exception?  (Also, it's customary to wait rather more than 10 minutes before accepting an answer, to give people in other parts of the world a chance… and to ensure that the answer you accept does actually answer the question fully!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CharSequence` is an interface and `String` class is already implemented that. Hence cast to `CharSequence` should be enough. `map` function returns **List<T>**

```
val list = arrayList.map { it as CharSequence }
```

With filtering null values

```
val list: List<CharSequence> = arrayList.filterNotNull()
```

Comment: This will crash if there are any null values in the source list.

Comment: You can filter null values before converting. I updated my answer.

Comment: The `map { it }` call is entirely redundant.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes `filterNotNull` already returns List<T>

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
val list: List<CharSequence> = arrayList.filterNotNull()
```

`filterNotNull()` removes any possible null values so you have a `List<String>`, which can be automatically up-cast to a `List<CharSequence>`.